# How to insert nested rows with a table cell below cell into table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I am new in iPhone app development. If the user clicks on the 2nd row button in the contacts section  and new cells are inserted into rows 3-5 according to array, and they later click on fist row button in scope section, adding new cells in rows 2-4 according to array, then the previous 3-5 cells will now be at rows 6-8.

I am totally confused to understand how is write the code for insert a row.

[image]

Here .m file of controller:

```
      //#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
      //#import "GeneralTableCell.h"
     @interface GeneralDetailViewController ()           <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
   {
   NSMutableArray *arrays,*arrayName,*arrayNames;
    NSString *sectionName;
   GeneralTableCell  *cell;
  }
  @end

  @implementation GeneralDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableViews.dataSource=self;
self.tableViews.delegate=self;

arrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Scope",@"Contacts",nil];
arrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithObjects:@"Project Member     Report",@"Venders", nil];
arrayNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithObjects:@"Scope Summary Report", nil];
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 -(IBAction)tapTOBack:(id)sender{

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
//- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:    (NSInteger)section
 //{
 //    return 45;
 //}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section
 {
 switch (section)
 {
    case 0:
        sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Scope", @"Scope");

        break;
    case 1:
        sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Contacts", @"Contacts");
        break;
    default:
        sectionName = @"";
        break;
 }
 return sectionName;
 }
 -(NSInteger )numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
 return arrays.count; 
 }

 -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section{
 NSInteger Number;
 if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"Scope"]) {

   Number=  [arrayNames count];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)Number);
     return  Number;
 }
else
   return [arrayName count];
//    return 2;
 }

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier=@"GeneralTableCell"; 
cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[GeneralTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                   reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
cell.btnExpandble.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.lblRowName.text= [arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.section ==0) {
    cell.lblRowName.text=[arrayNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.btnExpandble.tag=0;
}
else if (indexPath.section ==1){
     cell.lblRowName.text=[arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
        cell.btnExpandble.tag=1;
        [cell.btnExpandble addTarget:self action:@selector(tapToExpandCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
 } 
 return cell;
 }
 -(void)tapToExpandCell:(id)sender{

 }
 @end
```

Comment: we're confused too. You can't insert rows at index 5 when you have rows only upto 3. Update your question with sample image of what u r trying to do!

Comment: I want to according to array .

Comment: If any possibility then give solutions.